# Does for every integer $k$ exist a positive integer $n$ such that $F_n+k$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

For an integer $k$ , define $f(k)$ to be the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $F_n+k$ is prime (where $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number) , if such an $n$ exists and undefined else.

> Is $f(k)$ total , in other words , does always such a positive integer $n$ exist no matter what $k$ is ?

The $152$ "tough cases " in the range $[-10^5,10^5]$ (no prime for $n\le 10^4$) are :

```
-96715 -95551 -93963 -93439 -92293 -90791 -90119 -89607 -88817 -85723
-85445 -85343 -83733 -82697 -81635 -81037 -81005 -78035 -77741 -77397
-77313 -76851 -76519 -75977 -75923 -75089 -74995 -74919 -74273 -74129
-73893 -72665 -72183 -71921 -71535 -71469 -71315 -70967 -69983 -69873
-69411 -67367 -67123 -66929 -64163 -63633 -62677 -62531 -62407 -61277
-60979 -59753 -59219 -58533 -58269 -57885 -57401 -57103 -55811 -55097
-53145 -52603 -52277 -52221 -52193 -50567 -50447 -48841 -47217 -46905
-46903 -45839 -44589 -43981 -43537 -41743 -40681 -40649 -39591 -38097
-36805 -36803 -36323 -35957 -35929 -34971 -30345 -28965 -25145 -23695
-23163 -22707 -22023 -21813 -20617 -20147 -20077 -18717 -15471 -15067
-12333 -12123 -12061 -11649 -11643 -11441 -9919 -9341 -9087 -7505
-5151 -4115 6313 6851 7123 10591 11009 11561 13651 14475
19391 23843 25753 27727 27871 30282 30547 32053 33813 43711
45165 49351 53227 62177 64617 65953 66669 68149 69541 74325
74397 75249 78625 78693 85447 86085 88487 93687 93763 94485
94979 97945
```

I think , small factors are not forced , no matter what $k$ is and considering the grwoth rate of $F_n$ (just exponential) , we can expect the existence of infinite many $n$ for every $k$

Comment: Sorry, how does exponential growth hints having infinitely many primes? As "probability" of $n$ to be prime is $\frac{1}{n\ln n}$, shouldn't we expect finitely many primes in sequence $x_n$ if $\sum \frac{1}{x^n \ln x_n}$ converges? (also, wikipedia clames it's an open question if case $k = 0$ has infinitely many solutions)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Please, avoid doing that. Use the features of the forum, like bookmarking or following the question.

Comment: @mihaild The growth rate is not $n^n$ , but $p^n$ , where $p=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$. The logarithm of $p^n$ is $n\cdot \ln(p)$ and the expected number of primes is $\ln(p)$ times the harmonic series which diverges. Of course , this is only a heuristic and even for the case $k=0$ , it is open whether infinite many $n$ give a prime. However , for the conjecture we only need one $n$ doing the job.

Comment: f(6313)=25224 , f(6851)=13224 , f(-4115)=14496

Comment: @Peter ouch, my bad, the "probability" should be $\frac{1}{\ln x_n}$, not $\frac{1}{n \ln x_n}$. Should this mean that there is an answer for most $k$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, $f(k)$ is not total.

Reference https://oeis.org/A361902 for $k\ge 0$, where it states that if $k\equiv 14475 \pmod {1647030}$ then there is no solution.

The OEIS page links to a proof by Robert Gerbicz [here](http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/2023-March/074410.html).

```
Set T=2*3*5*7*11*23*31=1647030, then the Fibonacci sequence is periodic mod
T using period=240.
So need to check only the first 240 Fibonacci numbers, and for
each of them T and 14475+fibonacci(k) is not coprime, and of course bigger
than 31, so 14475+fibonacci(k) is composite for the first 240 k values, but
then for every k.
```

It also states that currently the solutions for $f(7123)$ and $f(11009)$ are unknown and are at least $F_{60000}$ (and, per the question, now checked to $F_{100000}$).

https://oeis.org/A322004 is the equivalent for $k\le 0$.

Comment: We have $f(7123)>10^5$

Comment: $f(7123) > 760\ 000$.

Comment: Trying to construct equivalent proofs for $7123$ and $11009$ the numbers quickly become unmanageable. The period to check for $14475$ was only $240$; for $11009$ it is at least $1.87 \times 10^{14} (187298727462000)$  and for $7123$ at least $1.43 \times 10^{20} (143303244288805228320)$.

Comment: $10^{14}$ seems manageable though (we only need $\mathcal O(\log n)$ operations per check). What was your value of T?

Comment: @jorisperrenet For $11009, T=1775259516743490088245028314990$, with the set of primes in order found: $\{7, 2, 23, 3, 19, 5, 181, 11, 2441, 4951, 83597, 41, 26501, 167, 53\}$. I want to be clear that this is a minimum because there may be undiscovered primes. I update $T$ and the period based on the smallest new prime that is a factor of $F_n+11009$ whenever $\gcd(T, F_n+11009)=1$.

Comment: @nickgard, factoring the first 500 values of $F_n + 11009$, I found that the minimum prime factors of the numbers also included other large numbers like `988628788417` and 
 `5470624001581` for $n = 126$ and $n=360$, respectively. Causing $T$ to increase a lot. Also, from sieving $f(7123)$ up to $10^8$ (and some past that) I could not factor all numbers and had to perform primality checks.

Comment: @jorisperrenet Agreed. I just re-ran and found the first of those. I would think somebody somewhere has tried this before. It seems an obvious thing to do.